# Pass ASP.Net GridView from one page to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to pass all the gridview value into another page 
I have one gridview in PatientDetails.aspx page and one button as below

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDoctorList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvDoctorList_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="gvDoctorList_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPID" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("PatientId") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName = "Select" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientId" HeaderText="PatientId" SortExpression="PatientId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="firstname" HeaderText="firstname" SortExpression="firstname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="lastname" HeaderText="lastname" SortExpression="lastname" />                                
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sex" HeaderText="sex" SortExpression="sex" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDatabaseConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [PatientId],[firstname], [lastname], [sex] FROM [PatientDetails]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Button ID="btnformatric" runat="server" Text="formatric3d" OnClick="btnformatric_Click" OnCommand="btnformatric_Command" />
```

on codebehind of PatientDetails.aspx is as below

```
protected void btnformatric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gvDoctorList.SelectedRow != null)
    {
        Server.Transfer("Patientstaticformatrix.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select a row.')", true);
    }
}
```

Now on the second page name Patientstaticformatrix.aspx the code behind is as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        GridView gvDoctorList = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("gvDoctorList");

        GridViewRow selectedRow = gvDoctorList.SelectedRow;
        Response.Write("PatientId: " + selectedRow.Cells[0].Text + "<br />");
        Response.Write("firstname: " + selectedRow.Cells[1].Text + "<br />");
        Response.Write("lastname: " + selectedRow.Cells[2].Text + "<br />");
    }
}
```

I had debug the code in second page....the value for gvDoctorList is null as well as the selectedRow is showing error of nullreference.

Can you please let me where I am wrong?

Comment: why do u want to transfer the control - a simpler choice will be to access the data that was bound to the grid.

Comment: i want the patientid value into the another page nothing else....and want to insert the selected patientid and image of patient in the second page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i have seen your previous question also, So i can suggest you one thing, rather than keeping your gridview in session(which is expensive) you can use `RowCommand` event, and after having `button` here i don't think you need checkbox or `chk_CheckedChanged` event, you can pass the `PatientID` to your next page there you can write query to insert selected row data to your new table.

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged"  
         AutoPostBack="true" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPID" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("PatientId") %>'> 
       </asp:Label>
      <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandArgument='<%# 
       Eval("PatientId") %>' CommandName = "Select" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>



 protected void gvDoctorList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "select")
            {
                int pID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                // either put ID in session and check 
                Session["PatientID"] = Convert.ToString(pID);
                Server.Transfer("Patientstaticformatrix.aspx");
            }
        }
```

On page_Load Event

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string pID = Convert.ToString(Session["PatientID"]);
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pID))
            {
              int patientID = Convert.ToInt32(pID);
             //Call Stored procedure which will insert this record with this ID
             // to another table
            }    

    }
```

Comment: i try with ur code it give me error on line : int pID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); that Input string was not in a correct format.....what to do with this?

Comment: what's datatype of `PatientId` ?

Comment: patientid is int as well as autoincrement in sql server

Comment: Is PatientID unique ?And this error means `PatientID` cannot be converted into Int type.Check updated answer but use it only if PatientId is unique or do you have any primary key ?

Comment: Have you set `CommandArgument` in your gridview as here `<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandArgument='<%# 
       Eval("PatientId") %>' CommandName = "Select" />`

Comment: If yes than please post you updated code, something wrong here it must work .

Comment: patientid is primary key and not allow the null

Comment: yes it working fine now.....i put the commandargument....thanks a lot it really help.

Answer (score 4):

Try using Session Variables. You can set the GridView into a Session variable that can then be retreived later so long as the same session is still active.

You can use the following code to set the Session Variable on your first page :

```
Session["gvDoctorList"] = gvDoctorList;
```

And then to retreive from the variable on your second page :

```
GridView gvDoctorList = (GridView)Session["gvDoctorList"];
```

For more information on Sessions see the [MSDN Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

Comment: should i set the session in checkbox change event or somewhere else?

Comment: You can set the session variable where you like, but I wouldn't set it until you require it. Like the following in your `btnformatric_Click` : `Session["gvDoctorList"] = gvDoctorList; Server.Transfer("Patientstaticformatrix.aspx");`. That way you are not using the memory space until you require it.

Comment: I cannot direct get the gridview control gvDoctorList in session....that means I need to first set the loop of gridview then inside that i need to set the session value...what do you think?

Comment: downvoted. bad practice. too big an object to hold in session in terms of memory consumption and performance. you should never do such things (even if it works). you will incur a big hit.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas please see my new extended answer below. I think I have addressed any concerns with using the Session Variable as I have with this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have decided to add a second answer based on the correct comments from Ahmed, The session variables really shouldn't hold the amount of data of the gridview due to memory issues.

The following should work accordingly for what I assume you are doing :

Essentially when you are selecting the row to go to the next page you are trying to retrieve the data of that row onto the new page. Is this Assumption correct? If so then you have a number of options for you to use.

Again you could use the Session Variables to store the data of the row once extracted on the first page :

```
protected void btnformatric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (gvDoctorList.SelectedRow != null) {

        GridViewRow selectedRow = gvDoctorList.SelectedRow;

        Session["PatientId"] = selectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        Session["firstname"] = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        Session["lastname"] = selectedRow.Cells[2].Text;

        Server.Transfer("Patientstaticformatrix.aspx");
    } else {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select a row.')", true);
    }
}
```

Essentially here you are on the first page and you get the data from the row. You then store this data in session variables and you can use the following to find the data from the next page :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null) {
        //Retrieve values from Session Variables
        Response.Write("PatientId: " + Session["PatientId"].ToString() + "<br />");
        Response.Write("firstname: " + Session["firstname"].ToString() + "<br />");
        Response.Write("lastname: " + Session["lastname"].ToString() + "<br />");
    }
}
```

You also have a second option of using Query Strings to pass the data. Although for this method I believe you will have to change the `Server.Transfer("Patientstaticformatrix.aspx");` to be `Response.Redirect("Patientstaticformatrix.aspx");`

Below is an example on using Query Strings :

```
protected void btnformatric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (gvDoctorList.SelectedRow != null) {
        GridViewRow selectedRow = gvDoctorList.SelectedRow;
        //Create URL with Query strings to redirect to new page
        Response.Redirect("Patientstaticformatrix.aspx?parentid=" + selectedRow.Cells[0].Text + "&firstname=" + selectedRow.Cells[1].Text + "&lastname=" + selectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
    } else {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select a row.')", true);
    }
}
```

And to retrieve the values from the `Request.QueryString` object on the second page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null) {
        //Retrieve values from Query Strings
        Response.Write("PatientId: " + Request.QueryString["parentid"].ToString() + "<br />");
        Response.Write("firstname: " + Request.QueryString["firstname"].ToString() + "<br />");
        Response.Write("lastname: " + Request.QueryString["lastname"].ToString() + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Both of these solutions should meet your requirements, however they are both slightly different. The `Session Variable` solution is probably the preferred method as it will stop users from being able to see all of the data passed (if you need to pass confidential information) where as the Query String values will be available to anyone who can see the URL.

For more information on Session Variables and Query Strings see the below resources :

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28VS.100%29.aspx)

[Request.QueryString Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

@Nunners answer is ownsome, but can also try with following way:

on anothoer page's pageload event fetch grid like:

```
GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
```

All the technique is given below:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Selected-Row-of-ASPNet-GridView-control-to-another-Page.aspx

Refer above doccument.

Comment: i have refer the link what u suggested....but in my case the GridView1 is name as gvDoctorList.....so i have replace it....still only null reference is coming....

Comment: @Pratik see this  http://rajudasa.blogspot.in/2011/08/aspnet-passing-gridview-control-from.html

Comment: The problem would be, what if the page is moved into a masterpage or usercontrol? this will not work.

Comment: yes ahmed you are correct i have both page inside the master page....so i m trying your solution of rowcommand...Hope that it work fine

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that you should create the same gridview on another page. This is how 99% of ASP.NET sites work since that page at some point will be writing/updating/deleting data. Or just use the same page - why redirect to show the same data?

Comment: i want to get the select value from the gridview and insert the selected patientid into the sql table....but in the another page....bec. i want to insert the image of patient and ofcourse the patientid

Comment: so why not do this on the same page? :)

Comment: i have camera configure in the other page so that the reason, it's not possible on same page

Comment: I see. Well that's simple. Basically on this page that has the grid, let them enter/update details and then do the call to the DB which will give you back an ID on success, take that record ID and pass it to the next page to do the camera shot then when confirmed, update the table using that image with the recordID.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution:

In Source aspx after grid databind:

```
Session["gridtoexcel"] =  yourgrid;
```

In destination aspx

```
 var grid = ((GridView)Session["gridtoexcel"]);

            gridToExcel.Columns.Clear();
            foreach (DataControlField col in grid.Columns)
                  gridToExcel.Columns.Add(col);
            
            gridToExcel.DataSource = grid.DataSource;
            gridToExcel.DataBind();
```

**this way i can 'clone' exact grid to another page. if you need some css style don't forget of add them in destination page**

*PS: gridToExcel is your destination grid*