# Passing of data from gridview to a new page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

It is something very simple but  i am stuck on this for ages.
So i had created a datatable and got the data onto a gridview. Great
Made the Sheet_id clickable and when clicking it i will direct to a new page.
However i want to get the sheet_id which i selected from the gridview in order to use it for other sql query.

How do i pass that sheet_id from one page to another page using the linkbutton.

This is ExistingSheet.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdSheet" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CssClass="tablesorter table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tblCtr"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="hdnSheetId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SNO")%>'> </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sheet ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="sheetId" CommandName="sheet_id" CommandArgument='<%# Eval( "sheet_id")%>' Text='<%# Eval( "sheet_id")%>' OnClick="" PostBackUrl="~/SheetDetail.aspx">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is ExistingSheet.aspx.cs

```
 protected void grdSheet_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("SheetDetail.aspx" + e.CommandArgument);
    }
```

This is the page i wanted to get the data to SheetDetail.aspx.cs

```
  public void FillGridSheet()
    {
        eExistingSheetQuery existingSheetQuery = new eExistingSheetQuery();
        grdSheetDetail.DataSource = existingSheetQuery.DisplayReportSheet(**SHEET ID TO BE PLACED HERE**);
        grdSheetDetail.DataBind();
    }
```

This is eExistingSheetQuery.cs

```
 public DataTable DisplayReportSheet(string sheetId)
{
       try
    {

    conn = new SqlConnection(estocktake);
    conn.Open();

    DataTable dtd = new DataTable();
    GridView gvd = new GridView();

    cmds = new SqlCommand("Select ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (order by sheet_id)  as SNO, csd.Barcode, csd.ItemId, pm.Description, csd.Quantity " +
                "from CountSheetDetails csd " +
                "join ProductMaster pm on pm.Barcode = csd.Barcode and pm.ItemId = csd.ItemId " +
                "where csd.SheetId = '" + sheetId + "' and pm.Status ='A';",conn);
    adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();

    adpt.SelectCommand = cmds;

    cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
    adpt.Fill(dtd);
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();

    for (int i = 0; i < dtd.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dtd.Rows[i]["SNO"] = i + 1;
    }
    return dtd;
    }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           conn.Close();
           conn.Dispose();
           return null;
       }
}
```

i wanted to use the id to beable to use it for the next query that i am going to pull from SQL

I had seen a few example but i do not think i really understand. Any suggestion will be great. thanks!

Comment: I think you're missing proper URL parsing strings in grdSheet_RowCommand(). Maybe "SheetDetail.aspx?SheetID="+... etc

Comment: Also provide all your code in relation to this, so we can help you better - what does eExistingSheetQuery() do? Does it really give back a DataSource? If not, then that's another problem.

Comment: @Fandango68 hi sir, i added it and the sheetid is to use for this funtion

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is a way to pass data from one `GridView` to another, but on a different page?

Using a loop mechanism, I suggest you loop through your source `Gridview` and copy them into your destination `GridView`. Get this to work first on a **single page** first - ie `GridView` to `GridView`.

For example, you'll need a trigger. Here's a Button trigger to get the data ...

> GridView1 = your source GridView
>
> GridView2 = your destination GridView

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnName1"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnName2"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnName3"));

        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        {            
            if (((CheckBox)gvr.Cells[4].FindControl("CheckBox")).Checked == true)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ColumnName1"] = ((Label)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("Label")).Text;
                dr["ColumnName2"] = ((Label)gvr.Cells[1].FindControl("Label")).Text;
                dr["ColumnName3"] = ((Label)gvr.Cells[2].FindControl("Label")).Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView2.Rows)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ColumnName1"] = ((Label)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("Label")).Text;
            dr["ColumnName2"] = ((Label)gvr.Cells[1].FindControl("Label")).Text;
            dr["ColumnName3"] = ((Label)gvr.Cells[2].FindControl("Label")).Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Once you get this to work, **your way,** then we figure out how to pass the data across different web URLs.

One approach is to use SessionState[]. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8055/Transferring-page-values-to-another-page).

The concept is basically about passing data into memory, which is the SessionState or ViewState, and then retrieving that data from the receiving page via it's PageLoad() event. OR you save the data into a temporary table, and reload it again onto the new page, using standard DataSource attributes.

Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266128/pass-asp-net-gridview-from-one-page-to-another-page#19267185) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8055/Transferring-page-values-to-another-page).